# How can I access k8s cluster in windows from the vmware ubuntu desktop

Tags: kubernetes, vmware, minikube, vmware-workstation

I start a k8s cluster on windows 10 desktop with minikube. And The ip of the windows is `192.168.10.11`.

```
$ ipconfig

Ethernet adapter :

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.10.11
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.10.1

Ethernet adapter VMware Network Adapter VMnet1:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.27.1
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Ethernet adapter VMware Network Adapter VMnet8:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.121.1
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.121.2
```

```sh
minikube start --apiserver-ips=192.168.10.11 --listen-address=0.0.0.0
```

Get the k8s config

```sh
kubectl config view
```

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority: C:\Users\Administrator\.minikube\ca.crt
    extensions:
    - extension:
        last-update: Mon, 24 Jan 2022 21:04:16 CST
        provider: minikube.sigs.k8s.io
        version: v1.25.1
      name: cluster_info
    server: https://127.0.0.1:60180
  name: minikube
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: minikube
    extensions:
    - extension:
        last-update: Mon, 24 Jan 2022 21:04:16 CST
        provider: minikube.sigs.k8s.io
        version: v1.25.1
      name: context_info
    namespace: default
    user: minikube
  name: minikube
current-context: minikube
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: minikube
  user:
    client-certificate: C:\Users\Administrator\.minikube\profiles\minikube\client.crt
    client-key: C:\Users\Administrator\.minikube\profiles\minikube\client.key
```

I have a Ubuntu 20 desktop in vmware workstation which is installed the same windows using NAT as the network adapter.

I copy the content of `kubectl config view` to `~/.kube/config`, and copy the following files:

```
from windows  -> to ubuntu
C:\Users\Administrator\.minikube\ca.crt -> /home/myname/.minikube/remote/ca.crt
C:\Users\Administrator\.minikube\profiles\minikube\client.crt -> /home/myname/.minikube/remote/profiles/minikube/client.crt
C:\Users\Administrator\.minikube\profiles\minikube\client.key -> /home/myname/.minikube/remote/profiles/minikube/client.key
```

modify the `~/.kube/config`

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority: /home/myname/.minikube/remote/ca.crt
    extensions:
    - extension:
        last-update: Mon, 24 Jan 2022 20:37:47 CST
        provider: minikube.sigs.k8s.io
        version: v1.25.1
      name: cluster_info
    server: https://192.168.10.11:60180
  name: minikube
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: minikube
    extensions:
    - extension:
        last-update: Mon, 24 Jan 2022 20:37:47 CST
        provider: minikube.sigs.k8s.io
        version: v1.25.1
      name: context_info
    namespace: default
    user: minikube
  name: minikube
current-context: minikube
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: minikube
  user:
    client-certificate: /home/myname/.minikube/remote/profiles/minikube/client.crt
    client-key: /home/myname/.minikube/remote/profiles/minikube/client.key
```

By the way, the IP of ubuntu is `192.168.121.130`.

Everything is ready. Try to use `kubectl get po` to test the connection, but get the following error:

```
The connection to the server 192.168.10.11:60180 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

And I try to telnet the host server, and fail.

```
$ telnet 192.168.121.1 60180
Trying 192.168.121.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused

$ telnet 192.168.10.11 60180
Trying 192.168.10.11...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

I wanna know what is the mistake I made?

Answer (score 0):

**This is just a network connection error on your part.**

**Change the type of the VMware interface to `bridge` instead of NAT -** this way you will have your VM on the same network as your windows machine from which you're trying to connect.

You can of course just try to connect to `192.168.27.1` but I'm not sure if this will work since the connection is NAT'ed and if you don't configured it to forward connections on certain ports to a guest machine (your Ubuntu VM) then you won't be able to connect.

Additionally this `192.168.121.130` address you got is probably the "internal" Ubuntu address that's not visible behind the NAT.

Have a look at [how NAT works](https://www.computernetworkingnotes.com/ccna-study-guide/basic-concepts-of-nat-explained-in-easy-language.html) in general to have better understanding how the connection works in this case.

So - either configure port forwarding on your NAT interface (if possible) or change it to bridge (best solution in my opinion) or create another VM with bridge network interface.

I'm not providing any specific instructions where and what to click since I don't know the version of VMware you're using.